# How to execute javascript before submitting form from any button type consistently

Tags: javascript, html

I'm updating an existing application that has several different button types on some pages that submit forms. I need each button to be able to execute some javascript right before submitting a form. I put my js code in the `onsubmit` event of the form, but not all buttons execute it. I created a sample that shows 3 different buttons that all submit the form. Buttons 1 and 3 will display the alert I entered into the form's `onsubmit` event.  Button 2 does not. I know I could put the alert code in the `onclick` for button 2 before the `submit()` call, but I really need a way that is consistent with all buttons. I need all buttons to execute the alert in my sample and I want to update code in one place and have it work for all buttons that are submitting this form. Is this possible? Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Code:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form name="form1" action="x.html" method="get" onsubmit="alert('onsubmit javascript executed');">
         <br><br>
         <input type="submit" value="1. html input type submit">
         <br><br>
         <input type="button" value="2. html input type button with onclick" onclick="document.form1.submit();">
         <br><br>
         <button style="width:180px;margin-right:5px;height:30px" onclick="document.form1.submit();">
             3. html button with onclick
         </button>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Update: 1/15/2014
Thanks for the ideas, but unfortunately, it is not addressing the issue of creating one solution that works for all buttons that may cause a submit event.  I spent all day yesterday trying different options based on the responses of both Jordan and Benjamin but still have not had luck.  So I thought I would take a step back and explain why I am trying to do what I am asking about.

I have a classic ASP application.  On the pages that require input from the user, I am getting many users that are timing out and when they click a button that submits the page they lose their information.  So I am adding a javascript timer to the page to first warn the user they are about to time out and then let them know that they have timed out so that they can copy and paste their work somewhere else to save it.  A key point is that the way this app was designed is that most pages submit to a hidden iframe so that the page doesn’t have to be reloaded.  If the user times out they don’t know it because it happens in the hidden iframe and they think the app just locked up.

My solution to this problem was to create a javascript timer on the page.  It creates a variable with the start time that the page loaded and counts down each second displaying a javascript message at set times.  I set it up and it works great, with one exception.  If the user submits a page (to the hidden iframe), their session timeout gets reset, but my javascript variable that tracks time does not.  This would lead to them getting a timeout message when they have not really timed out.  My first thought was that this would be an easy fix because after the page loads I can write a javascript function that finds every form onsubmit event and prepend a line of code to update my timer variable.  However, based on my original question, this is an issue because the form onsubmit event is not being called if the button is not a submit button even though it calls the submit() function of the form.  Ideally, I wanted to provide code that could be added to each form page that would not require any other updates to that page.

Unless someone has a better idea, I think I’m going to have to update some existing code on each page.  For any `<input type=submit>` or `<button type=submit>`, the update to the form’s onsubmit is fine and that is handled automatically by the javascript code I add to the page that finds all the forms and updates the onsubmit event.  But for each `<input type=button>` and `<button type=button>` I will have to manually check their onclick event and each function that it might call to see if it calls the submit() function.  If it does, then I have to do like Jordan pointed out and make it call a function where I can enter my code before calling the submit().

Any ideas to address my issue or to suggest a different method are appreciated.  Thanks again.

Comment: Are you using any external libraries (e.g. jQuery)? This would make writing an answer a lot easier.

Comment: Not using jQuery.  It is just classic ASP, HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't returning false in the onclick handler for Button 2? I suspect there's a bug in your click handler, or you return `false`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - See my sample code above.  There is no return false.  Is there somewhere outside of the code in my sample that I should be looking?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could instead submit the form from an event handler on the non-standard buttons, and have your code execute beforehand:

HTML

```
<button onclick="formSubmitHandler()">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
function formSubmitHandler() {
    // your code
    document.form1.submit();
}
```

Comment: This is usually not the preferred way. Prefer `addEventListener` over inline `onclick` events.

Comment: While I agree, it follows the pattern that OP is using